# Salesforce subTab name change in the console app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tab, console, subtab-apps

I am trying to change the name of the subtab in the console app but it is getting stuck with the tab tille as "Loading...."  written this below code to get the issue but not working, can some one help me out for this ...

below is my code :
CMP

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/> 
    <div class="slds-card">
        <c:testLWC />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = cmp.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: focusedTabId,
                label: "Focused Tab"
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001m6uvQAA&title=in-the-lightning-console-workspace-api-getfocusedtabinfo-doesn-t-work-on-component-init) with using `getFocusedTabInfo` in the `init` handler in a controller. Due to race condition `getFocusedTabInfo` sometimes gives wrong tab information.
For your requirement, you should use `getEnclosingTabId` to get the tab id and then set the tab label

```
init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = cmp.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(response) {
        workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
            tabId: response,
            label: "Focused Tab"
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```